# How to get user list of my FB application? (v2.8)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My FB application only ask basic permission(uesr_id, user_name), and I want to get the user list of who gives permission to my FB application. (version 2.8)

Further, the final purpose is if I get a user_id today, through compare with my application user list, I can know if this guy is my application user or not.

To get this purpose, I tried `Graph API` and ask extra permission, if the user didn't show extra value, then he/she isn't my application user.
But, I don't wanna ask user extra permission on my online application, so I only have basic one(id and name), which could get them from any user...

I'm a little bit good at `javascript` but suuuuuper bad at `php` or other server-side language, so if the answer could be handle by `javascript` will be nice, but I think it can't, though.

Comment: You don't need anything more than the basic permissions. Basic permissions still require the user to authorize the app, which Facebook then considers to be a user of the application. Store the ID and name in your database.

Comment: thx, but my website is attacked by a guy(or guys) who keep sending fake user_id and user_name through my own api, so I can't figure out which user is really using my app or actually a fake user.  my database is full of ID and I can't tell which should I remove, help : (

Comment: Do you allow non-Facebook registration? Or is it only possible via Facebook?

Comment: only possible via Facebook, but I guess they open my javascript source code, find *.php and get its input key, then write a simple loop to keep calling my api. In this way they could call my api without getting through Facebook callback function

Comment: Send the access token to the server, and from there either make an API call to debug it, or to request user details. Anyone can send you fake ids; but the access token can hardly be “guessed.”

Comment: Great idea!! I gonna talk over with my back-end partner about that, thanks a lot!